# Left and Right Cosets in Abstract Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $H = \{e, (12)(34), (13)(24), (14)(23)\}$. Find all of the left cosets of $H$ in  $A_4$.Find all of the right cosets in $A_4$.

I understand how to find the cosets, but what is  $A_4$?

Answer (score 1):

$A_4$ is the alternating group on $4$ letters. In general, $A_n$ is the alternating group on $n$ letters. It is a subgroup of $S_n$ containing precisely the even permutations of $S_n$.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_group

Comment: So I guess I do not understand how to find the cosets. If aH represents my left cosets and H is my set. What would I use for a?

Comment: If $aH$ is a left coset, then I am not sure what you mean by 'what would I use for $a$'. To find $aH$ all you need to do is find $\{ah:h\in H\}$. Does this help?

Comment: Yes, Yes. Thank you.